# OpenID Connect for service-oriented architecture web portal

Tags: web-services, oauth, openid, single-sign-on, soa

I'm building a website using service-oriented architecture (SOA) principles.  When users visit the site in their browsers, the interface they see will be composed of resources delivered by several different services on the backend.

My question is how to use OpenID Connect (OIC) to implement SSO so that users log on through the site once and their browsers can automatically retrieve all the protected resources that are necessary.

The main conceptual difficulty I'm having is that everything written for implementing OpenID Connect seems to be oriented toward people creating monolithic third-party clients that authenticate with Google, Yahoo, etc.  In my case, however, the client is my web portal and the resource providers are my backend services.  Certain OIC concepts don't make sense to me in this context: for instance, the auth grant.  Are users supposed to authorize the web portal to access their information the first time that they log on?  That would be pretty absurd.

Or Is OIC the wrong tool for what I'm trying to do?